# Ionic2 close fab menu when button pressed

Tags: angular, ionic2, floating-action-button

How can I close the open FAB menu when a button in the menu was pressed?

Here's my button.

```
<ion-fab bottom center >
<button ion-fab><b>Hello</b></button>
<ion-fab-list side="top">
<button ion-fab (click)="refresh()"><ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon></button>
```

What would I have to add to `refresh` to make the whole FAB close?
Can I somehow reference the html object from within the code? Similar to the way iOS handles it's outlets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add `#fab` to the `ion-fab` tag:

```html
<ion-fab bottom center #fab>
    <button ion-fab (click)="refresh(fab)"> 
        <ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon>       
    </button>
</ion-fab>
```

and use the `FabContainer` method `close()` to close the FAB menu (if opened) at the beginning of any function called by your FAB buttons, e.g.:

```js
import { FabContainer } from 'ionic-angular';

// remember to pass the fab from client side
refresh(fab?: FabContainer): void {
    if (fab !== undefined) {
      fab.close();
    }
    (other function stuff...)
}
```

Comment: Great! Where is `FabContainer` defined / which module do I import it from? The API doc is quite sparse?

Comment: `FabContainer` is in `ionic-angular` (I updated my answer). Yeah, the API doc is still not covering everything. Sorry, I forgot where I found this trick, probably in some tutorial.

Comment: In fact it is burried in the comments, but without the `import`

Comment: Shouldn't the fabcontainer be passed in the function call? 
`(click)="refresh(fab)"`

Answer (score 0):

Closing FAB in html file without .ts function; you can use `fab.close()` in html tag:

```
<ion-fab bottom left  #fab>
  <ion-fab-list side="top">
    <button [navPush]="cart" (click)="fab.close()" *ngIf="loggedIn" ion-fab>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

It is so simpler and also You can use multiple function for a single event (for example `(click)` event):

```
      <button *ngIf="loggedIn" (click)="logout()" (click)="fab.close()" ion-fab>
```

Don't forge place `#fab` in  tag: `<ion-fab #fab>`

Answer (score 0):

For new versions working only this solution (I know, i know, timeouts...):

TS:

```
@ViewChild('fab') _fab: IonFab;

public closeFab(){
    let t = setTimeout(() => {
        this._fabRight.close();
    }, 100);

}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" #fab>
<ion-fab-button color="secondary">
    <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
</ion-fab-button>
<ion-fab-list side="start">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="closeFab()">
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```